# I have an issue both when pushing in localhost and in production (heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

when pushing on my local host I have an issue that I dont know how to solve because I don't understand the message in my commande line : [image: My command line error message]

```
➜  benbollat git:(master) rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.1.5 application starting in development 
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
Exiting
/Users/arnaudlegarrec/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/puma-5.6.2/lib/rack/handler/puma.rb:63:in `run': wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1) (ArgumentError)
    from /Users/arnaudlegarrec/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.0.9/lib/rack/server.rb:297:in `start'
```

I have the same issue when pushing on production

Here is my gemfile :

```html
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '3.0.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails', branch: 'main'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.5'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 1.1'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 5.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 5.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.4', require: false

gem 'devise'
gem 'pundit'
gem "geocoder"
gem 'cloudinary', '~> 1.16.0'

gem 'autoprefixer-rails', '10.2.5'
gem 'font-awesome-sass'
gem 'simple_form', github: 'heartcombo/simple_form'
group :development, :test do  gem 'pry-byebug'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'dotenv-rails'

  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 4.1.0'
  # Display performance information such as SQL time and flame graphs for each request in your browser.
  # Can be configured to work on production as well see: https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler/blob/master/README.md
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.3'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 3.26'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '>= 4.0.0.rc1'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

I have already uninstall 100% of my gems and re-install theme (bundle) but the problm still the same

here is my pum.rb file :

```html
# Puma can serve each request in a thread from an internal thread pool.
# The `threads` method setting takes two numbers: a minimum and maximum.
# Any libraries that use thread pools should be configured to match
# the maximum value specified for Puma. Default is set to 5 threads for minimum
# and maximum; this matches the default thread size of Active Record.
#
max_threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }
min_threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MIN_THREADS") { max_threads_count }
threads min_threads_count, max_threads_count

# Specifies the `worker_timeout` threshold that Puma will use to wait before
# terminating a worker in development environments.
#
worker_timeout 3600 if ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV", "development") == "development"

# Specifies the `port` that Puma will listen on to receive requests; default is 3000.
#
port ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }

# Specifies the `environment` that Puma will run in.
#
environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "development" }

# Specifies the `pidfile` that Puma will use.
pidfile ENV.fetch("PIDFILE") { "tmp/pids/server.pid" }

# Specifies the number of `workers` to boot in clustered mode.
# Workers are forked web server processes. If using threads and workers together
# the concurrency of the application would be max `threads` * `workers`.
# Workers do not work on JRuby or Windows (both of which do not support
# processes).
#
# workers ENV.fetch("WEB_CONCURRENCY") { 2 }

# Use the `preload_app!` method when specifying a `workers` number.
# This directive tells Puma to first boot the application and load code
# before forking the application. This takes advantage of Copy On Write
# process behavior so workers use less memory.
#
# preload_app!

# Allow puma to be restarted by `rails restart` command.
plugin :tmp_restart
```

Comment: Hi @Arnaud, it would be really hard to debug this error without more information. Could you please post your Gemfile and your config/puma.rb? 

One thing you can try, is to use the "rails" binary provided by Rails itself, so you will be sure you are loading the proper Rails environment instead of relying on the global gem. You can test it by: "./bin/rails s"

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have post my Gemfile and my puma.rb file . When I run 
" ./bin/rails s " the error message that I have posted is showing on my terminal .